# show the following inequalities

Tags: integration

Show
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(2-2F(x))^2-1\right)\geq 0$, where $F(x)$ is the c.d.f. of standard normal distribution.

Can anyone give some pointers on how to proceed? thanks.

Comment: HINT:  $$0\le F(x)\le 1$$

Comment: Yes. But how can this help the proof?

Comment: Note the components of the integrand.  Are any of them negative for any $x$?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Note that the cumulative distribution function satisfies the inequalities

$$0\le F(x)\le 1$$

for all $x$.